# Multiplication table using binary operator oveloading gives error

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

When i execute the below code it shows no error in turbo c++ 4.5 . But when i run it it gives me an error like 

"General protection exception 0x00EA processor fault".
does my code contains any error. i dont know where to ask.any suggestions would be helpful.

this is the code

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
const size=10;

class tab 
{
int m[size];
public:
tab();
void disp();

friend tab operator *(int a,tab t3);
};

tab::tab()
{
for(int i=1;i<=size;i++)
{
m[i]=1;
}
}

void tab::disp()
{
for(int i=1;i<=size;i++)
{
cout<<m[i];
}
}

tab operator *(int a,tab t3)
{
tab t;
for(int i=1;i<=size;i++)
{
t.m[i]=a*t3.m[i]; 
}
return t;

}

void main()
{
tab t2,t1;
clrscr();
t2=2*t1;
t2.disp();
getch(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, indexes starts from 0, not 1.

So your loop should look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
```

instead of

```
for (int i = 1; i <= size; ++i)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you go out of bound in c/c++ you will surely have run-time error in latest operating systems and some compilers also gives you the same error beforehand to save you from any other crash. As you're exceeding the limits by writing

```
i<=size;
```

in for loop you'll finally reach at the index i=10, whereas you've indexes from 0-9 for your array size which is 10. So you get a run-time error. You can write it as

```
i<size;
```

and your starting limit that is i=1 is correct but it will start the loop from second value as indexes start from 0 in c/c++.